# Rails: Increase Selenium::Webdriver timeout to more than 45 seconds, say 150 seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, watir

[image]I am using webdriver gems in my Rils app:

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.46.2'
gem 'watir-webdriver', '~> 0.6.11'
gem 'watir-webdriver-performance', "~> 0.2.4"
```

About once or twice a day I get the following error in production, I understand this is because, 'WebDriver uses port 7054 (the "locking port") as a mutex to ensure that we don't launch two Firefox instances at the same time'.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45 seconds
```

Is there a way to increase the timeout of the webdriver to say 150 seconds? Or any other workaround?

thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

The 45 seconds is defined in a constant of the `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Launcher` class. Ruby let's you redefine constants, so you can change the value using `const_set`:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Launcher.const_set('SOCKET_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 150)
```

Note that this will give you a warning about redefining a constant. If you want to avoid the warning, you will have to remove the constant first:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Launcher.send(:remove_const, 'SOCKET_LOCK_TIMEOUT')
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Launcher.const_set('SOCKET_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 150)
```

(While this will let you change the timeout, I am not sure whether or not this will solve your actual problem.)